# InvalidFeatureException in jpmml while trying to load in java

Tags: pmml

my pmml file link. generated by R-Tool

[pmml file on google drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B18pDaxxV05aS2k3RkdLZnRuWjQ)

here is my java code..

```
PMML model = null;
    File inputFilePath = new File("/home/equation/iris_rf.pmml");
    try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(inputFilePath)) {
        model = org.jpmml.model.PMMLUtil.unmarshal(is);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }

    // construct a tree predictor based on the PMML
    ModelEvaluator<TreeModel> modelEvaluator = new TreeModelEvaluator(model);
    System.out.println(modelEvaluator.getSummary());
```

exception ---

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jpmml.evaluator.InvalidFeatureException: PMML
at org.jpmml.evaluator.ModelEvaluator.selectModel(ModelEvaluator.java:528)
at org.jpmml.evaluator.tree.TreeModelEvaluator.<init>(TreeModelEvaluator.java:64)
at com.girnarsoft.Pmml.main(Pmml.java:24)
```

any idea? why getting this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must instantiate `org.jpmml.evaluator.ModelEvaluator` subclass that matches the top-level Model element of your PMML file.

Currently, you're instantiating `org.jpmml.evaluator.tree.TreeModelEvaluator`, which corresponds to the [`TreeModel` element](http://dmg.org/pmml/v4-3/TreeModel.html). However, you should be instantiating `org.jpmml.evaluator.mining.MiningModelEvaluator` instead, as the top-level Model element in your PMML file is the [`MiningModel` element](http://dmg.org/pmml/v4-3/MultipleModels.html).

In general, you should construct `ModelEvaluator` instances using the `ModelEvaluatorFactory#newModelEvaluator(PMML)` factory method.